# What kind of torques cause an object to precess?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque, precession

In studying precession, my textbook (Taylor's *Classical Mechanics*) makes the assumption that a top spinning about its symmetric axis, but tipped at an angle $\theta$, will precess nicely so long as the torque due to gravity is small enough that we can consider the tops angular momentum $\vec{L}$ to be mainly about its symmetric axis regardless of precession.

This raises the question of what will happen to a spinning top if the torque due to gravity is very great and causes the top's angular momentum to be not mainly about its symmetric axis?

More generally, what kind of torques will cause something to precess (and yeah, I know that free precession exists which is another thing entirely [or at least I hope so]).

Comment: The question is not particularly clear. Adding a stronger gravitational torque will introduce [nutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation), but that does not mean that the precession will go away. Are you asking in which conditions the nutation vanishes and you get a 'pure' precession? Or what sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I think that nutation is definitely part of what I'm looking for here. I later read up on nutation and it makes sense where that comes from. But I guess I'm also wondering what happens when the torque is tremendously large. Can you have a really violent precession? Or does the object just slam into the ground?